# Do Brisbane and Darwin airport charge for trolley?

Tags: australia, airports, brisbane, bne

Does one have to pay anything to use the trolley at Brisbane and Darwin airports in Australia ? If yes, how much do they charge and do the machines accept bills or coins ?

Comment: International or domestic terminals?  It can vary - Sydney makes domestic travellers pay but international travellers can get them for free.

Comment: International terminal in Brisbane and domestic in Darwin. Flying in from Dallas. Then Brisbane, then taking a connection to Darwin from Brisbane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Brisbane International Airport** provides trolleys free of charge in international terminal, but charges **AU$4** in the domestic terminal.

> At the International Terminal, baggage trolleys are provided free of
>   charge and are located in the car park and on Levels 2 and 4. For
>   passenger convenience small trolleys for hand luggage and shopping are
>   also provided in the Level 3 Departures Lounge.
>
> At the Domestic Terminal, trolleys are available for a fee of AU$4.
>   Trolleys are located on the left hand side of the Domestic Terminal
>   pick up and drop off road.

Source for [Brisbane Airport](http://www.bne.com.au/passenger-information/get-around-terminal)

**Darwin Airport** provides trolleys free of charge.

Source for [Darwin Airport](http://www.darwinairport.com.au/passenger-information/terminal-information)